# HDD Won't connect / system won't read it. Not sure what dmesg output means`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fdisk, external-hdd, dmesg

I have a hdd that I pulled from an old windows laptop, I don't think there's any information on it that I want to keep. I was going to format it to ext4 or something.

Yesterday when I connected and tried to do something I got an error message about an unclean filesystem

When I run `fdisk -l` it just hangs and I have to close the terminal.

I've written the output of dmesg to a text file but I've not idea what the problems are that it seems to be listing.

[here is a link to the output](http://hastebin.com/inoroqaref.vhdl) I can't paste it in here because it's too long.

Here is an excerpt though to try and make this post a bit more self contained / give an idea of what is contained in the output. If anyone could help that would be great, cheers

```
[137892.604695] wlan0: associated
[137897.517506] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)
[137897.517818] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131115/nsarguments-95)
[147331.327969] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[147331.352116] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1631, idProduct=3200
[147331.352126] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[147331.352131] usb 3-2: Product: VLI Product String
[147331.352136] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: VLI manufacture String
[147331.352140] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000006283
[147331.353130] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[147331.353335] scsi9 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[147332.340647] usb 4-2: Device not responding to set address.
[147332.548313] usb 4-2: Device not responding to set address.
[147332.749069] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[147333.530241] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[147333.554400] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1631, idProduct=3200
[147333.554412] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[147333.554417] usb 4-2: Product: VLI Product String
[147333.554422] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: VLI manufacture String
[147333.554426] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000006283
[147333.556163] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[147333.556436] scsi10 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[147333.557216] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 14
[147335.029094] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Hitachi  HTS547575A9E     JE4O PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[147335.029374] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[147335.032836] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] 1465149165 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/698 GiB)
[147335.033330] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[147335.033333] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[147335.033829] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[147335.033832] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[147335.038517] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[147335.038520] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[147335.102150]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 < sdc5 sdc6 >
[147335.121804] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[147335.121809] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[147335.121812] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[147602.815372] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[147632.555007] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[147632.579109] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1631, idProduct=3200
[147632.579119] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[147632.579125] usb 3-2: Product: VLI Product String
[147632.579129] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: VLI manufacture String
[147632.579134] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000006283
[147632.580093] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[147632.580298] scsi11 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[147633.575692] usb 4-2: Device not responding to set address.
[147633.783359] usb 4-2: Device not responding to set address.
[147633.984083] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[147634.765262] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[147634.789376] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1631, idProduct=3200
[147634.789386] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[147634.789392] usb 4-2: Product: VLI Product String
[147634.789397] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: VLI manufacture String
[147634.789401] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000006283
[147634.790854] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[147634.791120] scsi12 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[147634.791635] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 15
[147656.494733] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[147656.511562] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e00
[147656.511566] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e40
[147656.626851] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[147656.643599] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e00
[147656.643602] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e40
[147662.763786] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[147662.780621] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e00
[147662.780625] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e40
[147662.891897] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[147662.908702] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e00
[147662.908705] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e40
[147663.024010] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[147663.040807] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e00
[147663.040811] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880327a60e40
[147663.041710] scsi 12:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[147751.783571] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[147768.504680] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[147768.528775] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1631, idProduct=3200
[147768.528786] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[147768.528791] usb 3-2: Product: VLI Product String
[147768.528796] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: VLI manufacture String
[147768.528800] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000006283
[147768.529776] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[147768.530051] scsi13 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[147769.525243] usb 4-2: Device not responding to set address.
[147769.728880] usb 4-2: Device not responding to set address.
[147769.929750] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[147770.710935] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[147770.734206] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1631, idProduct=3200
[147770.734208] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[147770.734209] usb 4-2: Product: VLI Product String
[147770.734210] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: VLI manufacture String
[147770.734211] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000006283
[147770.735356] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[147770.735492] scsi14 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[147770.735896] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 16
[147772.975132] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD32 00BEVT-75A23     01.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[147772.975725] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
```

---

edit - reran dmesg without usb drive connected, I ran it twice, one immediately after connecting and once a few seconds after

[first dmesg](http://hastebin.com/reroletuba.vhdl)

[second dmesg](http://hastebin.com/hogiyovojo.vhdl)

---

edit 2

I've used a superspeed port instead of a regular one, apparently this can make things off.

I have 4 USB ports, I'm not sure which are which in terms of speeds (they aren't coloured).

The first tests were done with Port 1, I shall now test for the others, to test this I'm simply connecting the drive using the [adaptor](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--7qvO0E18pc/VQQuJ7p82SI/AAAAAAAAdQw/_hmhGIOxRK4/w1095-h822-no/20150314_124717.jpg) and then running `dmesg > hdd.txt`:

#### [port 2](http://hastebin.com/nafudutefi.vhdl)

#### [port 3](http://hastebin.com/aculiberal.vhdl)

#### [port 4](http://hastebin.com/jogibosiwi.vhdl)

for my reference (which ports are which as I look at the laptop) :

```
port 2  | port 4
--------------------
port 1  | port 3
```

Comment: It looks like this disk is attached by USB? If you connect directly by SATA (assuming it is a SATA disk), this might eliminate the problem or clarify that it is indeed the disk (and not the USB interface) that is causing it.

Comment: @gogoud yes it is, via a [usb to sata connection](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--7qvO0E18pc/VQQuJ7p82SI/AAAAAAAAdQw/_hmhGIOxRK4/w1095-h822-no/20150314_124717.jpg)(I can't connect directly via sata, I don't get this problem using other drives with this cable). Apparently it seems as though there might be concerns (based on the output of dmesg) regarding my internal 750GB drive as well. I've no idea where to go from here in regards to checks / tests etc.

Comment: so I think this drive is WD [Scorpio Blue 320GB](http://www.wdc.com/En/library/sata/2879-701278.pdf)? Clearly the machine is very unhappy about it, but it seems to recognise two USB devices, is this the only one you are attaching?

Comment: Yes you're correct @gogoud. I'm sorry but there is also a USB flash drive connected. Is this polluting dmesg a bit? I can run it again without that connected (there's also  wireless keyboard and mouse dongles connected), cheers

Comment: yes please try without the USB flash drive, it should be clearer that way. The dongles shouldn't matter (I think).

Comment: I've just ran that @gogoud, [run 1](http://hastebin.com/reroletuba.vhdl) [run 2](http://hastebin.com/hogiyovojo.vhdl), run 2 was slightly after run 1.

Comment: The drive is a USB 2 device but you've plugged it into a USB 3 ("superspeed") port. They are not very compatible despite what the marketing tries to suggest.

Comment: Worth trying a USB2 port instead of USB3. But it looks like there is a hardware problem, and if it isn't the USB-SATA adapter then I would suspect the drive itself.

Comment: @roaima, please see the update, I have added logs for all 4 ports.

Comment: @gogoud I have added logs for all 4 four ports just now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem could be caused by:

1. a poor USB cable/adapter (see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1616677)); or
2. kernel issues - more info (re ArchLinux but might have wider applicability) [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158206); or
3. faulty hard drive...; or
4. power-related problem, especially that this drive may require more power than can be provided by the USB port and/or the adapter.

I think 4 above is quite likely the reason. Your drive was tested [here](http://www.storagereview.com/5400_rpm_speed_hitachi_s_travelstar_5k250_and_wd_s_scorpio_wd3200bevt) and was found to need 4.9 watts of power at start-up - particularly greedy I am afraid. The USB 3.0 spec provides a maximum power draw of 4.5 watts (USB 2.0 is only 2.5 watts) - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power). Probably your drive is just short of power when it is starting up.

You could try with a USB Y power cable (with 2 male ends and 1 female end); connecting this between your PC and your USB/SATA adapter *might* give your drive the oomph it needs. These cables are available quite inexpensively on Amazon and eBay. Alternatively there are some all-in-one SATA/USB adapters with 2 USB male ends - [example](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-USB-3-0-to-SATA-22P-2-5-Hard-Disk-Driver-Adapter-w-USB-Power-Cable-Adapter-/261644467925?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item3ceb39bed5).

Comment: That's pretty broad. As said previously the cable works with other drives, I doubt it's kernel related, power problem seems weird but turning things off and on again is never a bad call and number 4 seems to be the main issue. I'm guessing the file system on it is damaged (rather than the mechanics of it) but I don't know how to go about sorting that

Comment: @learner: A file system problem would present differently, this error message indicates something more fundamental. Can you be confident about this drive? Does it work with any other machine?

Comment: It said unclean file system originally (that's in the op), is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @learner: I think the unclean file system is a consequence of the hardware problem, not other way round, unfortunately. I have found WD drives to be pretty good on the whole but the 'Blue' range are their cheapest, and it is say 6 years old now...

Comment: @learner: I have changed my answer to add info about the possible (IMO probable) cause - lack of power. HTH.

Comment: Unplug all USB devices, power down. plug everything back in. boot into linux, still no go? It is a hardware issue would be my bet. You did say it was 6 years old out of an old box? how many times was that box moved around, kicked etc. Sounds like a cheap drive to replace anyways...